# Stop Present Push Notification while App is Inactive or in Background

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I want to stop notification to present when user has been logged out from my App.
I have tried below.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    print("\n>>willPresent notification")

    if sharedManager.instance.isLoggedIn {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }else{
         completionHandler([])
    }
}
```

This is working perfect when app is active.
But the problem is when the app is in background or inactive, This code is not work.

I checked for background mode, at that time the `willPresent notification`  and `didReceiveRemoteNotification` methods are not get called.

Which is the appropriate method get called while receiving push notification in background or Inactive Mode??

Comment: but in settings->notification here not any option for this
just available UISWitch dude which used to on/off the facility

Comment: @NazmulHasan - can you explain little bit more...not getting exactly so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to handle this condition.

You can ask your API developer to handle this at server side,

1. When user clicks on logout button, call API to logout and set the status, `isLoggedIn` to false
2. For every API, that will send the push notification to user, at server it first check for the user's logged in status and can send the notification accordingly.
3. On, Login again set `isLoggedIn` to true in db at server and then it will start receiving the notifications again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanx Bhavin, we did exact same. but the problem is in some case we are redirecting the user on login screen with out calling LOGOUT_API and we need to do that thing. Hence this situation is occurs.

Comment: Can you please elaborate that special case where you are redirecting the user to login screen

Comment: The case is when user tries 3 wrong attempt, we redirect to login.
but now, I got the answer,
we can set status "logged_Out" on third wrong API attempt.

Comment: thanxx to your last question... it helps to came me on the idea. thanx bro.@Bhavin Kansagra